# Removing straight line noise from image using openCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, hough-transform

I'm trying to clean a captcha image that has straight lines as noise in them.

[image: Captcha with straight lines noise]

I'm very new to OpenCV but from what I understand the best approach is to turn the image to black and white then using a Hough Line Transform to detect the lines and then mask them.

I did that here:

```
im_gray  = cv2.imread('download.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
im_bw_inverted = cv2.bitwise_not(im_bw)
```

`im_bw_inverted`:

[image: Black and white of Image]

I then detected the lines using the Hough Lines:

```
rho = 1
theta = np.pi / 180
min_line_length = 1
max_line_gap = 20
threshold = 50
line_image = np.copy(im_bw) * 0
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(im_bw_inverted, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), min_line_length, max_line_gap)

for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),1)
```

`line_image`:

[image: Lines Mask]

Using `inpaint` to mask it:

```
line_image_dilate = cv2.dilate(line_image, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (4, 4)))

dst = cv2.inpaint(im_bw_inverted,line_image_dilate, 1, cv2.INPAINT_NS)
```

`dst` Result:

[image: Result after inpaint]

Is there a better way to approach cleaning the image? The resulting image doesn't look that good is there a way to improve the result?

Comment: you can try a morphological closing after you remove those lines. nothing will fix those glyphs. sufficiently modern OCR can just recognize those glyphs even with those lines in the picture.

Comment: I suggest that this activity is unethical. Attempting to subvert the CAPTCHA protection shows a lack of respect for the owner of the server, whether they are doing it to protect their bandwidth or their business

Comment: @fmw42 attempting to subvert CAPTCHA is definitely unethical but that isn't what I'm doing. This is part of a university project to show how easily CAPTCHA can be bypassed and what can be done to avoid your CAPTCHAs being bypassed, I have no intention of using it in any unethical way.

Comment: if you want to make that point, make it by talking about deep learning becoming able to solve these.